# in 2d lists which way is the row and which is column?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

when reffering to 2d lists which is the correct way the rows/columns are ordered? I am having trouble following some of the q&a on this site and others ....I always imagined it as the second way I show but idk?

[[a ,b, c],[d, e, f], [g, h, i], [j, k, l]]

is for easy visualization this?:

- [a, b, c]
- [d, e, f]
- [g, h, i]
- [j, k, l]

(making it 4 rows x 3 columns)

or this:

- [a, d, g, j]
- [b, e, h, k]
- [c, f, i, l]

Comment: I prefer the first visualization, but I don't think there is a correct answer to this question.  If it is important, you should define a Matrix class.  You could include an appropriate constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

neither way is "wrong," as there is no right or wrong answer. rows and columns don't have meaning until displayed in a certain way. in memory, it's all stored linearly.

syntactically, all that matters is that if your 2d array is called `array`, then `array[0]` is a 1-dimensional array, and `array[0][0]` is an item.

however, it's very unusual for it to be considered any way besides the first way, as in English we read left to right, top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a row would be seen as `[a, b, c]`.  A column would be seen as `[a, d, g, k]`.  In the case of objects (i.e. a list or lists or an ArrayList of ArrayLists), it's a little different, but we can treat them similarly.